# Syntax error on using gtest with Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, googletest, ndk-build

I am trying use gtest with ndk, the ndk-build finds the dependences, but I have a sintax error on internal gtest file gtest-printers.h

```
external/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:170:9: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >}' and 'const BiggestInt {aka const long long int}')
     *os << kBigInt;
         ^
```

follows my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := my_module

GTEST_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../external/gtest

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_STLP_USE_NEWALLOC

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=                             \
    ...

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                            \
    ...

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${GTEST_DIR}/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lstdc++

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(GTEST_DIR)/lib/libgtest.a

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: This error often means that you're missing an include. This can happen because you have enough includes to find _some_ overload of `operator<<`, but not the one that is actually needed.

Comment: I discovered the error happens when I use the flag `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11`, is it possible use gtest with C++11 or not?

Comment: Yes, we have plenty of C++11 tests using gtest. What is the actual failing line of code (_your_ code, not from gtest).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in my AOSP tree (completely by accident). See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was try to call static gtest lib directly, instead of, I had to do it before:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
GTEST_DIR := ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/third_party/googletest/googletest
LOCAL_MODULE    := gtest

# flag for c++11
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${GTEST_DIR}/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${GTEST_DIR}/

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-all.cc              \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest.cc                  \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-death-test.cc       \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-filepath.cc         \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest_main.cc             \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-port.cc             \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-printers.cc         \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-test-part.cc        \
                   ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-typed-test.cc

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3):

We have encountered the same issue, and working solution was to use:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

instead of `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++11`. It must have set some different mappings of `long long int` in `stlport`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like C++11 + stlport is the bad combination for gtest. This isn't terribly surprising, given that stlport doesn't actually have any support for C++11 (some parts of it will work, others apparently won't). If this only causes problems when *building* gtest, you could just not use C++11 when building gtest, but still for your code.

If you can't use it from C++11 either, you're probably out of luck for now (there should be a better option available as soon as I find time).